# Is kernel did de-fragmentation

Tags: c, linux, udp, fragment, recv

When I received packet with `recv` at linux, is the kernel did de-fragmentation so I will get de-fragmentation data? Or should I take care of it on user-space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When receiving UDP data via a socket of type `SOCK_DGRAM`, you'll only receive the complete datagram (assuming your input buffer is large enough to receive it).

Any IP fragmentation is handled transparently from userspace.

If you're using raw sockets, then you need to handle defragmentation yourself.

Comment: How can I validate if socket is raw or `SOCK_DGRAM` by /proc/net/udp` ?

Comment: @axi85136Bcaoo.com You know the socket type by what is passed to the `socket` function.

Comment: Is `libpcap` using raw socket?

Comment: @axi85136Bcaoo.com You'll need to look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

ip fragmentation takes place at the IP level in the protocol stack.  The layers TCP and UDP already receive recomposed packets due to fragmentation, so the TCP can receive full segments (despite that TCP tries to neve send segments that result in fragmented packets) and UPD receive full datagrams to preserve datagram boundaries.

Only if you use raw sockets you'll receive raw packets. (this meaning fragments of IP packets) TCP gives you already reliable data streams (preserving data sequence, repetitions and retransmission of missing/faulty packets) and udp gives you the datagram as it was sent, or nothing at all.

Of course, all these modules are in the kernel, so it's the kernel that recomposes packets.  It's worth noting that, once a packet is fragmented in pieces, it is not recomposed until it reaches its destination, so it's the IP layer at destination who is responsible of reassembling the fragments.